# how to iterate through a binary search tree in python(no recursion)

Tags: python, loops, binary-search-tree

So far I have

```
def tree_iterate():
parent, current = None, self.root
lst = []
while current is not None: 
 if current.left not None:
  lst.append(current.item) 
  parent, current = current, current.left
 if current.right not None:
  lst.append(current.item)
  parent, current = current, current.right
```

(sorry about spacing I'm quite new at this)

I'm not quite sure how to iterate on both sides of the tree when current has left and right, without using recursion. My main goal is to have a list of all the nodes in this BST`enter code here`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid recursion? It's the most concise and clear method of doing tree traversal. An easy iterative way to get all the nodes in your tree is to use breadth first search (BFS). You can use a queue (a simple python list) for this.

Answer (score 7):

To get a list of all nodes in the BST iteratively, use Breadth-First Search (BFS). Note that this won't give you the nodes in sorted order:

```
queue = [root]
result = []
while queue:
    l = queue.pop(0)
    result.append(l)

    if l.left != None:
        queue.append(l.left)
    if l.right!= None:
        queue.append(l.right)
```

If you want the nodes in sorted order, you will need to simulate inorder traversal using a stack:

```
result = []
stack = [root]
while stack:
    stack[-1].visited = True
    if stack[-1].left != None and not stack[-1].left.visited:
        stack.append(stack[-1].left)
    else:
        node = stack.pop()
        result.append(node)
        if stack[-1].right != None:
            stack.append(stack[-1].right)
```